# how to use vpblendmd in avx-512 assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, simd, avx512

in the Intel® Intrinsics Guide it says Instruction: `vpblendmd zmm {k}, zmm, zmm`, I don't understand how to use the `{k}`, for example I write the following code:

```
vpblendmd   %zmm1,%zmm2,%zmm2{0xAAAA}
```

but it's wrong for compiling and the compiler reports the information `Error: unknown vector operation: '{0xAAAA}'`
so how can I use this instruction?

Comment: `{k}` has to be one of `{k1}` through `{k7}`, a mask register name.  In the machine code, it's a 3-bit field for the mask-register number, not a 16-bit immediate!  Look at compiler output for the intrinsic (https://godbolt.org/) to see it `mov` + `kmov` a value into `k1`.  You can't use immediate masks; AVX-512 doesn't have an instruction for immediate blends, unfortunately, even though there are only 8 qwords per ZMM vector so they could have included an instruction that took an `imm8` like in SSE4.1 / AVX1.  But x86 SIMD has never had instructions with 16-bit or wider immediates.

Comment: Ok, I get it, thanks